# Add tag to input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have such an input:

```
f.text_field :name
```

How can I add this tag to it: `data-hj-whitelist`

So that It looks something like:

```
<input type="text" name="name" data-hj-whitelist/>
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
f.text_field :name, data: { 'hj-whitelist' => '' }
```

Result is exactly as you want:

```
<input type="text" name="name" data-hj-whitelist/>
```